# Determine the dimension and find the actual matrix that satisfies the matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Determine the dimension and find the actual matrix X that satisfies the matrix equation:

$$(XA)^T=(A^T+3I)X^T,$$

where A is a 3x3 matrix and $T$ denotes transpose.

My answer:

On the left side, we have nx3 matrix multiplied by 3x3 matrix, so the result is nx3, taking transpose we have 3xn. On the right side, we have 3x3 matrix (in brackets) times 3xn matrix, so the result is 3xn. The same as above. So my answer is that X is nx3, where n is arbitrary.

I would be grateful if you could confirm whether my reasoning is correct. What should I do next?

Edit:

We use the fact that $(XA)^T=A^TX^T$, therefore

$$A^TX^T=(A^T+3I)X^T$$

so

$$A^T = A^T+3I$$

which leads to

$$0=3I$$

which is a contradiction, so the answer is that there is no matrix $X$ which satisfies that equation.

Comment: It is correct. You could use $(AB)^{T} = B^T A^T$. Your equation is easier when you transpose both sides.

Comment: Thank you, @user3257842. Could you please take a look at my edited question? I added the solution.

Comment: Remove the commas after the $$ equations so it will look nicer. Your solution is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: That isn't correct. $A^TX^T=(A^T+3I)X^T$ gives $A^TX^T=A^TX^T+3X^T$. Thus $3X^T=0$, i.e., $X=0$.

Comment: Yes. I've made a mistake in ignoring the case $X^T = 0$

Answer (score 1):

$()^=(^+3)^= A^T X^T+3X^T $

By definition of transpose:  $()^= A^TX^T$, hence $ A^TX^T= A^T X^T+3X^T $

thus $ 3X^T = 0  \Longrightarrow X=X^T = 0$